# ASP: OnTextChanged not firing where text="" in ddl

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a `ddl` in `updatePanel` that works fine. but when I select the first item {value:"null",Text:""} it doesn't fire.

C#

```
ddlCat.DataSource = DataBase.GetTable("select ymc_name,ymc_id from Y_MainCat");
        ddlCat.DataTextField = "ymc_name";
        ddlCat.DataValueField = "ymc_id";
        ddlCat.DataBind();
        ddlCat.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "null"));
        ddlCat.SelectedValue = "null";
```

html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCat" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="ddlCat_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubCat0" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCat" EventName="TextChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Try changing the event from "TextChanged" to "SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: @Sam Hood ,I tried already without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it does happen - when the `selectIndex`=0 then the event `onSelectIndex` doesn't fire.